# How to traverse all nodes of a TreePath recursively

Tags: java, defaulttreemodel, defaultmutabletreenode

I am trying to create a method that go through all nodes of a path. it will be used for a JTree and nodes will be files and folders. So it must go through the folders as well.

Here is my code:

Main setup:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
final DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
```

Search method:

```
public void search(TreePath path){

    Object o = path.getLastPathComponent();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) o;
    o = node.getUserObject();

    if(!node.isLeaf() && node.getChildCount() >= 0){
        Enumeration e = node.children();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            search(path.pathByAddingChild(e.nextElement()));
        }
    }
    else{
       node = node.getNextNode();
    }
}
```

So in my method I tied to specify if the node is a folder then go though it and follow the same process.  otherwise get the next node and so on.
But it does not work.

Any idea?

Comment: If you use Guava you could consider using a `TreeTraverser`

Comment: @fge No it's just a Java application.